# Can't plot dataframe when index is a date

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a CSV file that looks like this:

```
Date,Close
16-Mar-17,848.78
15-Mar-17,847.2
```

Whenever I try to load it in and set the date as the index by doing:

```
df = pd.read_csv("new_data.csv")
df.set_index("Date")
```

I get`ValueError: could not convert string to float: '18-Mar-16'`. **Why is this happening?** I thought you could set a date even if it was a string. I am a novice to pandas so it is most likely a simple misunderstanding.

**EDIT:**
I was reading the error on the wrong line, here is the chunck of code that throws the error.

```
df = pd.read_csv("new_data.csv")
Close = df.sort_index(ascending=True)
plt.plot(Close)
plt.gca().invert_xaxis()
plt.show()
```

Comment: convert string to proper datetime format, then you can use it for set_index('Date')

Comment: Works for me as shown (pandas 0.18.1). Please double check your example. What is the value of `pd` before changing the index?

Comment: @ShubhamNamdeo No need for conversion. Strings can serve as indexes.

Comment: Works for me too. Tell us the result of `pd.read_csv("new_data.csv")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now, you need to convert string `Date` to `datetime`:

```
Close['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(Close['Date'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues, all related with taking good care of the date data.
good practice is while loading data, using pandas functionality to load the date info.

```
df = pd.read_csv("new_data.csv", parse_dates=[0], infer_datetime_format = True)
```

where column[0] is where date column located.
and then pandas will do the "magic" and handle xticks of the plot nicely.